# S3 upload works locally but not when deployed to heroku

Tags: flask, amazon-s3, heroku

I've been working on this for a few days now, I finally got to the stage after I learned images/videos can't be stored in the filesystem in heroku to do a direct upload to s3 which works fine locally but all of a sudden when I deploy to heroku using my gitlab-ci it doesn't seem to work. I also don't see any errors anywhere, but when I check my s3 console the files don't upload.
This is my function to upload to s3 that works locally:

```
def S3_upload(BUCKET, current_user, file):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    print(file.filename)
    key = current_user + '-video/' + file.filename
    print(key)
    try:
        s3.put_object(Bucket=BUCKET, Key=key, Body=file)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

called by this:

```
@main_bp.route("/upload", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
@login_required
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files.get('video')
        if file:
            aws.S3_upload(BUCKET, current_user.username, file)
```

I was thinking it was something to do with my config vars, but when I call
`aws s3api list-buckets` in my ci it finds it no problem,

```
    "Buckets": [
        {
            "Name": "bucketname",
            "CreationDate": "2021-01-28T20:00:56.000Z"
        }
    ],
    "Owner": {
        "DisplayName": "username",
        "ID": "id"
    }
}
```

maybe its my heroku config? but I have AWS_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, and S3_BUCKET set in there too. Is there something I'm missing out on in the configs or something to allow it to put items into my s3 bucket from there?

UPDATe: Heroku logs as requested

```
2021-02-01T12:56:27.043630+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-02-01T12:56:28.399728+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=bbtestdeploy.herokuapp.com request_id=ca117732-7754-49e1-aa11-0e8f4ee06645 fwd="92.51.252.44" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=456ms status=200 bytes=1736 protocol=https
2021-02-01T12:56:28.400207+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.13.247.220 - - [01/Feb/2021:12:56:28 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1261 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_1_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.96 Safari/537.36"
2021-02-01T12:56:28.611957+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.13.247.220 - - [01/Feb/2021:12:56:28 +0000] "GET /static/css/home.css HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "https://bbtestdeploy.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_1_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.96 Safari/537.36"
2021-02-01T12:56:28.627660+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.13.247.220 - - [01/Feb/2021:12:56:28 +0000] "GET /static/css/register.css HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "https://bbtestdeploy.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_1_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.96 Safari/537.36"
2021-02-01T12:56:28.611715+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/home.css" host=bbtestdeploy.herokuapp.com request_id=2db09ad3-cb23-4361-a655-745a13b1d613 fwd="92.51.252.44" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=400 protocol=https
2021-02-01T12:56:28.627621+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/register.css" host=bbtestdeploy.herokuapp.com request_id=0b011a65-3826-4b53-b074-fab101a9f3ac fwd="92.51.252.44" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=2534 protocol=https
2021-02-01T12:56:28.968391+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=bbtestdeploy.herokuapp.com request_id=7a1b9652-5408-46c0-ad68-b11cb5678fcc fwd="92.51.252.44" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=400 protocol=https
2021-02-01T12:56:28.968789+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.13.247.220 - - [01/Feb/2021:12:56:28 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "https://bbtestdeploy.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_1_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.96 Safari/537.36"
2021-02-01T12:56:33.344110+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/video" host=bbtestdeploy.herokuapp.com request_id=00404468-b669-4f0c-8226-8527e325680b fwd="92.51.252.44" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=65ms status=200 bytes=1674 protocol=https
2021-02-01T12:56:33.406129+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/video.js" host=bbtestdeploy.herokuapp.com request_id=a9fa78ba-1c4c-45c0-bd99-419b682caceb fwd="92.51.252.44" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=2929 protocol=https
2021-02-01T12:56:33.344369+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.13.247.220 - - [01/Feb/2021:12:56:33 +0000] "GET /video HTTP/1.1" 200 1199 "https://bbtestdeploy.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_1_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.96 Safari/537.36"
2021-02-01T12:56:33.403916+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.13.247.220 - - [01/Feb/2021:12:56:33 +0000] "GET /static/css/home.css HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "https://bbtestdeploy.herokuapp.com/video" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_1_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.96 Safari/537.36"
2021-02-01T12:56:33.406075+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.39.168.78 - - [01/Feb/2021:12:56:33 +0000] "GET /static/js/video.js HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "https://bbtestdeploy.herokuapp.com/video" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_1_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.96 Safari/537.36"
2021-02-01T12:56:33.403558+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/home.css" host=bbtestdeploy.herokuapp.com request_id=08c82013-08da-4135-977e-48601065b22d fwd="92.51.252.44" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=400 protocol=https
2021-02-01T12:56:38.873181+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.39.168.78 - - [01/Feb/2021:12:56:38 +0000] "POST /upload HTTP/1.1" 200 290 "https://bbtestdeploy.herokuapp.com/video" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_1_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.96 Safari/537.36"
2021-02-01T12:56:38.873403+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/upload" host=bbtestdeploy.herokuapp.com request_id=3613a20b-adb1-44e3-9fdb-183af2b72916 fwd="92.51.252.44" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=8ms status=200 bytes=764 protocol=https
```

Update 2: Video.js file that sends the video recorded in browser to /upload

```
let constraintObj = { 
    audio: false, 
    video: true 
}; 


if (navigator.mediaDevices === undefined) {
    navigator.mediaDevices = {};
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia = function(constraintObj) {
        let getUserMedia = navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
        if (!getUserMedia) {
            return Promise.reject(new Error('getUserMedia is not implemented in this browser'));
        }
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            getUserMedia.call(navigator, constraintObj, resolve, reject);
        });
    }
}else{
    navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
    .then(devices => {
        devices.forEach(device=>{
            console.log(device.kind.toUpperCase(), device.label);

        })
    })
    .catch(err=>{
        console.log(err.name, err.message);
    })
}

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraintObj)
.then(function(mediaStreamObj) {

    let video = document.querySelector('video');
    if ("srcObject" in video) {
        video.srcObject = mediaStreamObj;
    } else {

        video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(mediaStreamObj);
    }
    
    video.onloadedmetadata = function(ev) {

        video.play();
    };

    let start = document.getElementById("startbtn");
    let stop = document.getElementById("stopbtn");
    let vidSave = document.getElementById("vid");
    let save = document.getElementById("saveVid")
    let mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(mediaStreamObj);
    let chunks = [];
    
    start.addEventListener('click', (ev) =>{
        mediaRecorder.start();
        console.log(mediaRecorder.state);
    })
    stop.addEventListener('click', (ev) =>{
        mediaRecorder.stop();
        console.log(mediaRecorder.state);
    });
    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(ev) {
        chunks.push(ev.data);
    }
    mediaRecorder.onstop = (ev) =>{
        let blob = new Blob(chunks, { 'type' : 'video/mp4;' });
        chunks = [];
        let videoURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        vidSave.src = videoURL;
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('video', blob, "video.mp4")

        save.addEventListener('click', (ev) =>{
            $.ajax ({
                url: "/upload",
                type: "POST",
                data: formData,
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false
            }).done(function(response){
                console.log(response);
            })
        })
    }})

.catch(function(err) { 
    console.log(err.name, err.message); 
});
```

Comment: Could you paste the logs as well? Perhaps there is an exception in there that provides a clue? Where does BUCKET come from?

Comment: @KarlSutt I've added them above I cant really see anything myself from there. But had an idea that maybe it was my bucket permissions for CORS: 
`[{ "AllowedHeaders": [
      "*"],
     "AllowedMethods": [
            "HEAD",
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE"],
   "AllowedOrigins": [
      "https://bbtestdeploy.herokuapp.com/"],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
] ` 
This is my current settings, any idea if these need to be changed to allow putobject from my heroku env?

Comment: And BUCKET is a string that is the name of my bucket

Comment: Is the filename getting printed on Heroku? Doesn't appear in the logs. Also the POST to /upload is only 764 bytes — is the video (I assume from naming) definitely getting uploaded from the browser?

Comment: @KarlSutt The filename doesnt get printed on heroku no, but it works fine locally, I'll update the question with my video.js file that records my video and sends it to /upload. I'm just confused as to why it would work perfectly on localhost but act differently when on heroku considering I've put in the credentials, and on my gitlab ci when i do list buckets the bucket is shown in the list

Comment: Hmm — that suggests that aws.S3_upload(...) isn't getting called, otherwise you'd see the filename in the logs.

Comment: Also, in your jQuery AJAX call, you probably should have the content type as "multipart/form-data", as you're sending binary data to the server.